# Get 404 error from Heroku when on localhost evetything ok. Java application

Tags: java, heroku, controller, localhost, http-status-code-404

I am trying to deploy my simple **java** application on **Heroku**. And I have successful status(in deploy) and it starts.
But when I am trying to get access to my controllers by https://herokuprojectest.herokuapp.com/main/status, I get **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**. And in heroku logs i have this message:

`at=info method=GET path="/main/status" host=herokuprojectest.herokuapp.com request_id=42c4069e-ceef-425b-8786-8ab4834b1b7b fwd="188.163.51.90" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=879 protocol=https`

But when I am trying the same on http://localhost:8080/main/status, everything is ok, i get **{"status":"ok"}** - answer from controller.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.heroku</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>9.0.30.0</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My Procfile:
`web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war`

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

   @GetMapping("/status")
   public ResponseEntity<Model> getStatus(Model model, WebRequest request) {
       model.addAttribute("status", "ok");
       return ResponseEntity.ok(model);
   }

}
```

I think that I have problem in my **pom** or **procfile**, or I can be wrong…
Does anyone see my mistake?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with Heroku, but maybe, there is some firewall issue? Filrewall allows request from localhost to localhost, but blocks request from outside? I had such issue with spring boot application.

Comment: @Igor_M, how can i check it? How did fix your problem?

Comment: I had client and server both running on my local machine. Client used localhost and everything worked. When server was running on my local machine but client was running on remote machine (some virtual machine provided by my organization) - all client requests failed. For me it was not really a problem because I used my local machine only for testing. I took second virtual machine, ran server on it. Server and client communicated without issues because these virtual machines didn't have any fierwalls.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this but:

1. Try the next procfile:
   `web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war --port $PORT`
2. Don't forget to build the project before upload with:
   `mvn package`
3. Are you sure about your `$JAVA_OPTS` var? In some cases developers should use different variations of it: `_JAVA_OPTIONS`, `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. If `JAVA_OPTS` is fine for your case, is it set up correctly?

I bet that your problem is in procfile.

Comment: I tried:
`web: java $_JAVA_OPTIONS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war --port $PORT`
`web: java $_JAVA_OPTIONS  -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war --port $PORT`
`web: java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war --port $PORT`

and have the same **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found**....

Comment: @Max everything in your .env file in your local app you need to add in the heroku dashboard. Is this done? And what else saying heroku --tail logs? Like I've understood, you can find some detail logs somewhere on your heroku Dashboard.